# How To Change HTML Structure of Shipping Form(cart page) in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping, forms

I have to change **HTML** of shipping form in **Cart page**. When I turned on **template path hint**, i got that the file is coming from `Shipping.phtml` file in the theme directory. But when I tried to open and edit the file, I found that the **form field is not there**. The form was rendering by the **`<script>`.**

I am not understanding where the form is coming from in the front-end. Please anyone help me to find the file, in which i can change the HTML structure of the form.

Thanks

Comment: describe in more detail, what you want to change.

Comment: I want to change classes of label and input , select filed , also the sequence of the form fields.